# Flagging Outliers using while loop and dynamic names along with mutate R

Tags: r, while-loop, outliers, mutate

I need to mark columns containing outliers in R -- preferably using a while loop for so its  easy to apply to other situations.  I would like to create a new variable for each column denoting if the outlier is in the greater than or lower than IQR bound for each column.

Assuming I'm using the txhousing dataset I am trying to end up with the following columns

city year ...  city city.out.up city.out.down year year.out.up year.out.down ...

My solution looks like this so far (I've tried using paste() so far):

```
while (i < 9) {
    iqr <- IQR(df[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
    fiver <- fivenum(df[,i])
    lowerbound <- fiver[2] - (1.5*iqr)
    mutate(df, VAR.out.up = case_when(df[,i] <= lowerbound ~ 1, df[,i] > lowerbound ~ 0))
    upperbound <- fiver[4] + (1.5*iqr)
    mutate(df, VAR.out.up = case_when(df[,i] >= upperbound ~ 1, df[,i] < upperbound ~ 0))
    boxplot(df[,i], main = colnames(df[,i]))
  i = i + 1
}
```

Is there a way to create dynamic variable names using a predetermined suffix using mutate?

Comment: for dynamic generation of column names, you may look into the walrus operator `:=`, with something similar to `mutate(df, "{VAR}.out.up := case_when.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that ingests your vector of interest and returns a two column data table with column names `out.down` and `out.up`.. You can adjust the function `f()` below for your purposes:

```
f <- function(x) {
  q = quantile(x,p=c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm=T)
  data.table(out.down = x<q[1], out.up = x>q[2])
}
```

Then just apply the function to the numeric columns of your dataset

```
library(data.table)
df = setDT(ggplot2::txhousing)
cbind(df, df[,lapply(.SD, f), .SDcols = is.numeric])
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `dplyr::across()` instead of a for loop and rewrite your loop as a function.

Note the following points:

1. I did intentionally not include the plot. Let's do the plotting in a different function.
2. `IRQ()` and `fivenum()` only work on numeric columns, so the approach below only targets those and skips non-numeric columns.
3. I'm not sure if your calculation of the outliers is correct, please have a look.

```r
detect_outlier <- function(x, bound = c("lower", "upper")) {
  bound <- match.arg(bound)
  iqr <- IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  fiver <- fivenum(x)
  
  if (bound == "lower") {
    bound <- fiver[2] - (1.5 * iqr)
    `%compare%` <- `<=`
  } else {
    bound <- fiver[4] + (1.5 * iqr)
    `%compare%` <- `>=`
  }
  ifelse(x %compare% bound, 1, 0)
}

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

txhousing %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                list("out.down" = detect_outlier,
                     "out.up" =  ~ detect_outlier(.x, "upper")),
                .names = "{.col}.{fn}"
                )
         ) %>% glimpse # for better printing

#> Rows: 8,602
#> Columns: 25
#> $ city               <chr> "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilen…
#> $ year               <int> 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 200…
#> $ month              <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, …
#> $ sales              <dbl> 72, 98, 130, 98, 141, 156, 152, 131, 104, 101, 100,…
#> $ volume             <dbl> 5380000, 6505000, 9285000, 9730000, 10590000, 13910…
#> $ median             <dbl> 71400, 58700, 58100, 68600, 67300, 66900, 73500, 75…
#> $ listings           <dbl> 701, 746, 784, 785, 794, 780, 742, 765, 771, 764, 7…
#> $ inventory          <dbl> 6.3, 6.6, 6.8, 6.9, 6.8, 6.6, 6.2, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6…
#> $ date               <dbl> 2000.000, 2000.083, 2000.167, 2000.250, 2000.333, 2…
#> $ year.out.down      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ year.out.up        <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ month.out.down     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ month.out.up       <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ sales.out.down     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ sales.out.up       <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ volume.out.down    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ volume.out.up      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ median.out.down    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ median.out.up      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ listings.out.down  <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ listings.out.up    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ inventory.out.down <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ inventory.out.up   <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ date.out.down      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ date.out.up        <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
```

Below is a `for` loop version, which I would prefer over a `while` loop here:

```r
df <- txhousing

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  x <- df[[i]]
  if (!is.numeric(x)) next
  iqr <- IQR(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  fiver <- fivenum(x)
  lowerbound <- fiver[2] - (1.5*iqr)
  var_nm <- names(df)[[i]]
  df <- mutate(df, !! sym(paste0(var_nm, ".out.down")) := case_when(x <= lowerbound ~ 1, x > lowerbound ~ 0))
  upperbound <- fiver[4] + (1.5*iqr)
  df <- mutate(df, !! sym(paste0(var_nm, ".out.up")) := case_when(x >= upperbound ~ 1, x < upperbound ~ 0))
  # boxplot(df[,i], main = colnames(df[,i]))
}

df %>% glimpse

#> Rows: 8,602
#> Columns: 25
#> $ city               <chr> "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilene", "Abilen…
#> $ year               <int> 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 200…
#> $ month              <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, …
#> $ sales              <dbl> 72, 98, 130, 98, 141, 156, 152, 131, 104, 101, 100,…
#> $ volume             <dbl> 5380000, 6505000, 9285000, 9730000, 10590000, 13910…
#> $ median             <dbl> 71400, 58700, 58100, 68600, 67300, 66900, 73500, 75…
#> $ listings           <dbl> 701, 746, 784, 785, 794, 780, 742, 765, 771, 764, 7…
#> $ inventory          <dbl> 6.3, 6.6, 6.8, 6.9, 6.8, 6.6, 6.2, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6…
#> $ date               <dbl> 2000.000, 2000.083, 2000.167, 2000.250, 2000.333, 2…
#> $ year.out.down      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ year.out.up        <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ month.out.down     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ month.out.up       <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ sales.out.down     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ sales.out.up       <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ volume.out.down    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ volume.out.up      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ median.out.down    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ median.out.up      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ listings.out.down  <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ listings.out.up    <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ inventory.out.down <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ inventory.out.up   <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ date.out.down      <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ date.out.up        <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>